# Integrate Gitolite with Gerrit ACL.

Tags: gerrit, gitolite

had configured gitolite for ACL in GIT, with the introduction of Gerrit how to integrate both of them, for Acess control. while still having gitolite for ACL and  not to use Gerrit's.

Comment: Why do you want or need to run Gitolite and Gerrit at the same time? Which Gitolite features are missing from Gerrit?

Comment: I wanted to use Gerrit only for codereview, and retain the gitolite for Access control. Ex:  workflow , User -> gerrit-> gitolite-> git. I wanted to make sure while cloning from gerrit, the  access controls should be from gitolite. Not sure if i am answering your question rite. Basically i wanted to integrate Gitolite with with gerrit.

Comment: I understand _what_ you're trying to do, but I don't understand _why_. What's the benefit of having two overlapping systems running at the same time?

Comment: I got what you are saying, scrap gitolite and use only gerrit for Access control ?

Comment: Yes, unless you have a clear reason for using Gitolite.

Comment: Thanks, that clears my doubt.. Would there be a quick and easy way of importing ACL's to gerrit.

Comment: Don't know about quick and easy, but Gerrit ACLs are configured in a plain text file stored in the refs/meta/config ref so it should be reasonably easy to write a script for the conversion.